# Publishing a Windows Form with Local Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, visual-studio-2015

We have a windows form application with a local .mdf database. It has all its required functionality, but it wont work without connecting to the associated database. This is probably an incredibly simple solution, but we cannot figure out WHAT needs to be installed on the target PC for this to work. For reference, our connection string is as follows

```
    const string connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = |DataDirectory|ourDataBaseName.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
```

The problem is, this, and the published program version, works fine on OUR computers, but with our test computer, we cannot for the life of us get this thing working. My questions then  are the following

1. Do we need to change the connection string?
2. What needs to be installed on the target PC to make it connect to the database? We've tried many of the offered prerequisites that are in visual studio, but none seem to work.

For reference, the database and program were made in visual studio 2015, and does not integrate with any other applications, and is intended for use on a single pc. Aside from installation, it shouldn't need connection to the internet to function.

Any help or direction to helpful resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what have you tried. That connection string requires the SqlLocalDb installation and just a copy of your MDF file in the same folder of your application.

Comment: Also be sure to install the same version of LocalDB used by your dev machine (in VS2015 this should be SqlServer Express 2014 or upper) If you had installed the Sql Server Express 2012 then the connection string is _(LocalDB)\v11.0_

Comment: We tried that, still not operating. We have tried installing previous versions of Sql Server Express and LocalDB. We are almost certain it's a really minor, easy to fix thing, we're just banging our heads against a wall at this point. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: I don't think that this will make a difference but your connectionstring seems to miss a backslash before the file name. _|DataDirectory|\ourDataBaseName.mdf;_

Comment: That was an error in my pasting over, but good spot

Comment: I have the same issue here, hope you find the solution.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using SQL Server Compact, which can be packaged with your application? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58b77a2c-1092-44c8-824f-3bc8cc4a5cce/how-to-publish-a-windows-application-with-the-new-localdb?forum=winformssetup

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, I had an application with a local database, which was created in sql server 2017, and when I published it, it only worked on my PC and nobody elses. After struggling a long time to solve this I found out that I needed to install both SQL Server Express 2017 AND the localdb version on the target device. 
Keep in mind that even after installation and rebooting the machine, MSSQL Service has a tendency to not be running and you'll face the same error, you'll have to start it manually.

Comment: so its not enough to just install the local db in prerequisites? we also need to install ssms to the client machine? (this is my understanding on your answer)